# Excluding logback from spring boot GRADLE ONLY

Tags: java, gradle, logback

This is a common question, i'm making this question up as there is no proper answer on SO.

So you're working with spring boot and you have in your gradle file something like:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version:'2.0.4.RELEASE'
// Logging
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.28'
```

Now when you run your program you get some sort of silly error like

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.TurboFilter

OR equall confusingly

> LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath

I have the answer down below.

If you in the future come across this problem but now it needs an extra step, please edit my answer as well to capture it. Goodness knows how many, plausibly millions of hours have been lost to this terrible problem.

Please don't mention maven, this is a gradle-only problem.

Answer (score 1):

Stick this in your gradle file. I put it in the space immediately above "dependencies"

```
configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
   all*.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
   all*.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-core'
}
```

So it looks like:

```
configurations {
...
}
dependencies {
...
}
```